# Separate gravity from acceleration in Wp7 ( using acceleration Api only)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to WP7 development and working on a project (wp7 app) where I need to get ONLY gravity force using accleration API (I think I can do some thing using [Motion Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202984%28v=vs.92%29.aspx))  but It requires window phone to support  Compass and  Gyroscope as well.So Is there any way to separate gravity  from accleration or only get gravity forces on X, Y and Z axis using only accelration (as I want my app to run on wp devices where there is no  Compass and Gyroscope).

Also in android there are some methods likes

- Linear Acceleration
- Low pass / high pass filters etc
  Do we have such kind of support in Wp7?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phone itself doesn't know what force is caused by acceleration and what by gravity. You would need information from other sensors to be able to do the math to separate the values. That's what Motion API is for.

So, your only chance is to use Motion API. It will fall gracefully if the device doesn't have the necessary sensors, but will work if there are:

> The Motion API used by this sample requires all of the supported
>   Windows Phone sensors, and therefore these sample applications will
>   fail gracefully but will not work properly on devices without the
>   necessary sensors or on the device emulator.

Comment: It means my application can not work on the windows phones where compass and gravity does not supported?

Comment: I think so, yes. Although I think that MOST of the devices do have a compass besides accelerometer, especially the latest generation of devices. Still, there may be a device that doesn't, that's true, but I don't know about one. I am also not sure if compass is enough to separate the values, I think it's not, you would need a gyroscope...

Answer (score 0):

There was a post on the [Windows Phone Team blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/09/08/using-the-accelerometer-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) about implementing a High pass / low pass filter on the accelerometer data. I've used this with fairly good results.

Comment: According to this blog, do you think we can remove gravity factor from acceleration?  As in android using Low pass / High pass filter we can isolate/remove force of gravity [See under 'Using the Accelerometer'](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html)